# javascript remove duplicates from array of objects

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I have below array of objects,

```
var parsedData =  [
        {
            "ID": "16",
            "DESCRIPTION": "SMAATO"
        },
        {
            "ID": "26",
            "DESCRIPTION": "BIDSWITCH"
        },
        {
            "ID": "1572",
            "DESCRIPTION": "BIDSWITCH"
        }
    ]
```

i have removed duplicate from this using below code,

```
var flags = [], l = parsedData.length, i;
            for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
                if( flags[parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION]){ 
                    if(attribute.toLowerCase() == "supply"){
                        console.log("coming!!"+parsedData[i].ID+"---"+parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION);                       
                    }
                    continue;                   
                }
                flags[parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION] = true;
                groups_array.push({     
                    id: parsedData[i].ID, 
                    text: parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION
                });                 
            }
```

but what i need to achive is, if id is differnt and description same means need to append id to first one and remove duplicate one like this,

```
[
    {
        "ID": "16",
        "DESCRIPTION": "SMAATO"
    },
    {
        "ID": "26,1572",
        "DESCRIPTION": "BIDSWITCH"
    }
]
```

How to get this one help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
if (flags[parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION]) {
    let id = groups_array.map(item => item.text).indexOf(parsedData[i].DESCRIPTION);
    groups_array[id].id = groups_array[id].id + "," + parsedData[i].ID
    continue;                   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its working.But the arrow function will support in all browsers?.In IE its not working.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can replace arrow function with: function(item){return item.text}. I've no idea If it'll work in all browsers, it's beyond my expertise, but googling 'arrow function browser support' should help. Perhaps, the details might be a topic for another, new SE question.