# How to remove duplicates from the array of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `let arr = [ ['A1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['A2','B1'], ['A1', 'B1']]`. Which has duplicate `['B1', 'A1'] and ['A1', 'B1']` of different direction still it should be removed and expected output should be `[ ['A1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['A2','B1']]`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're going to likely need a custom function, any inbuilt function would look for an actual duplicate (as opposed to your pseudo-duplicate). Have you tried anything? It'll be easier for us to correct a reasonable attempt than to write something from scratch that may or may not do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript remove duplicates from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732985/javascript-remove-duplicates-from-array-of-objects)

Comment: [There’s work to be done, whether it is homework or an assigned task , the person to whom it was assigned is expected to complete it. Even if it seems the task is too hard or there isn’t a clear starting point, an effort should be made.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter with a `Set` with normalized values (sorted and joined).

```js
const
    getValue = ([...a]) => a.sort().join(),
    array = [['A1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['A2', 'B1'], ['A1', 'B1']],
    result = array.filter((s => a => (v => !s.has(v) && s.add(v))(getValue(a)))(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the required result, for each element in the input array we create a `key`.

We'll use this key to create an entry in a map object, and duplicate items will be eliminated since they will share the same key.

Once we have all items in our map, we'll use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the resulting (unique) array.

```js
let arr = [ ['A1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['A2','B1'], ['A1', 'B1']]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    // Create a key based on what we consider a duplicate.
    let key = el.sort().join("-");
    acc[key] = acc[key] || el;
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach is to use the lodash function [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) using the iteratee `el => el.sort().join('-')`:

```js
let arr = [ ['A1', 'B2'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['A2','B1'], ['A1', 'B1']]

const result = _.uniqBy(arr, el => el.sort().join('-'));
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Please tell me the name of the pattern used to solve this problem. When we group objects by properties and return the answer as `Object.values(...)`. I call it grouping by hash but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: It's similar to a group by hash, however we discard 'collisions', retaining only the first element returning a given hash, so it's probably more like the lodash _.uniqBy function (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function removeRepeatedArray(arrays){
 const map = new Map();
 
 for(let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
   // convert each array to a unique key 
   // subarrays needs to be sorted first
   const key = arrays[i].sort().join("");
 
   if(map.has(key)){
     // if exists replace it with undefined
     // you can use splice method to remove the repeated array it index i
     // I am using filter to keep the logic simple
     // using splice will require updating i
     arrays[i] = undefined;
   }else{
     map.set(key, arrays[i])   
   }
 }

  return arrays.filter(el => el !== undefined);
}
```